# Getting records for distinct results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (NerdsTable) as follows:

```
--------------+---------------------+--------------
    name             school              id
--------------+---------------------+--------------
    Mike             China              5000
    Joe              Serbia             100
    Ana              Serbia             100
    Rats             Khaleesi Land      100
--------------+---------------------+--------------
```

When I issue a query like this:

```
select distinct school from dbo.NerdsTable;
```

I get back results:

```
[china, serbia, Khaleesi Land]
```

When I issue a query like this:

```
select * from dbo.NerdsTable where school = 'china'
```

I get results back like this:

```
[Mike, China, 5000]
```

What I want to do is get a distinct list of schools, and for each school, show the student: Hence, I tried to combine the two queries into something like this:

```
select * from dbo.NerdsTable where school = (select distinct school from dbo.NerdsTable);
```

However, I get an error stating that:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value.
```

The error makes sense, but I am unsure as to how I can instruct the sql server query to loop through all distinct results and execute the select * statement.

Comment: please show expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use in clause

```
select * from dbo.NerdsTable 
where school in (select  school from dbo.NerdsTable);
```

because the school for subselect are more then one

Comment: ah you are correct. such a small character got me ;)

Comment: `distinct` in that `sub-query` is pretty useless

Comment: This will return all rows where school is not null, i.e. all rows in this case.

Comment: This certainly fixes the issue but the logic seems pointless here. You could change the where predicate to "School is not null" and it would return the same information.

Comment: You guys are all correct. When I think about it, my solution could really have been select name from dbo.NerdsTable. It would have achieved the same thing. I wonder if the performance would differ

Comment: This is a bizarre answer to a bizarre question. School is going to be in the subquery every time unless it's empty, and we don't see any examples of that in the sample data...